What is the emission spectrum of an igniting match?

I took this photo of a burning match just after striking. There are clear emission lines rippling throughout the spectrum and a huge peak in the orange. Nowhere online could I find a lit match spectrum to help decipher this. I don't have a wavelength scale for this image, so I've had some doubts in identifying the lines. I think it might be oxygen, which has similar lines in the orange, green, and blue, but I can't understand why the one peak is so much brighter. The other molecules present would be phosphorous, sulfides, and even cellulose from the wood. Any thoughts?

Always blame sodium if possible.   It's just really bright even in trace amounts.

The intense orange line is probably from a mix of phosphorus and sodium.
You can calibrate your spectrophotometer by looking at a compact fluorescent bulb with it; you'll see a prominent characteristic pair of lines in blue & green which come from mercury.

@BowlOfRed mentioned sodium too. Where would sodium be coming from? Sodium does not seem to be an ingredient in matches from what I've been reading.

@jmadden The sodium line is quite bright.  It can be visible even if sodium is present as a contaminant.  Without calibration, it's hard to say if that's what your line is.   But it would be good to rule it out as a first step because it's just so common.

@jmadden, there's sodium contamination everywhere. flame spectroscopy requires it be removed carefully so it doesn't get in the way of your measurements.
